# One line iteration through dictionaries in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
G2 = {'a': {'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 'b': {'a': 1, 'c': 1}}

b = G2.values()

for i in b:
    for key, value in i.items():
        list.append(key)

#result: ['c', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

Can I get the same result but using a list generator? 
I tried it like this:

```
list2 = [key for key, value in i.items() for i in b]

#but i get: ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 6):

just chain the dictionary values (aka keys) using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, and convert to list to print the result:

```
import itertools

G2 = {'a': {'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 'b': {'a': 1, 'c': 1}}

#['c', 'b', 'a', 'c']

result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(G2.values()))

print(result)
```

result:

```
['c', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

note that the order is not guaranteed as you're iterating on dictionary keys.

Variant without using `itertools` with flattening double loop inside comprehension (which is probably closer to your attempt):

```
result = [x for values in G2.values() for x in values]
```